# Can set password for Script code in Google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

i write some code of file test1  in file `code.gs`

I share file test1 with some user.

But i only want anybody have password can edit file code.gs

Can set password for Script code in Google app script?

Comment: Google login password is enough. If you share code/sheet to them, it'll be shared.

Comment: Instead of setting up a password, just share the script only with the people who should be a be to edit the file and give them "Can Edit" permissions.

Comment: How can not share script? i only want user edit data, not allow edit script.